# How to put an html element over a fabric.js element

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to put a button over a fabric.js element which is inside of a fabric.Group.

How do I get the top-left corner coords relative to the canvas container of a fabric element and then set it to the button?.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d9sp16yc/2/

I've tried things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870315/how-to-add-a-text-box-popup-jquery-tooltip-or-similar-to-a-fabric-js-image-wit) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829475/how-to-get-the-canvas-relative-position-of-an-object-that-is-in-a-group) but I don't get the results that I want. The button gets slightly moved to right or left / bottom or top.

Another thing is that the `setSize` function is scaling the group when the window gets resized (just to get a responsive behaviour):

```
function setSize() {
  var width = $('.container').width();
  var height = width * 0.6;
  canvas.setWidth(width);
  canvas.setHeight(height);
  group.scaleToWidth(width);
  canvas.centerObjectH(group);
  // setPos($('#btn'), rect);
}
```

And the problem is that this affects the way the coords are being calculated.

Is this possible to put it in the top-left corner of the fabric object even when the window gets resized?

I really need a quick solution for this so I would appreciate any suggestion/help to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this [(Interaction with objects outside canvas)](http://fabricjs.com/interaction-with-objects-outside-canvas). I hope it helps...

In a nutshell you can use the absolute coordinates of an object inside the canvas to position an HTML element out of the canvas.

Here is the code and a screenshot from the website. It simply positions HTML button over a fabric image element and assigns move event on the image, so when you move the image, the button follows it.

[image]

```
(function() {
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
  fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

  fabric.Canvas.prototype.getAbsoluteCoords = function(object) {
    return {
      left: object.left + this._offset.left,
      top: object.top + this._offset.top
    };
  }

  var btn = document.getElementById('inline-btn'),
      btnWidth = 85,
      btnHeight = 18;

  function positionBtn(obj) {
    var absCoords = canvas.getAbsoluteCoords(obj);

    btn.style.left = (absCoords.left - btnWidth / 2) + 'px';
    btn.style.top = (absCoords.top - btnHeight / 2) + 'px';
  }

  fabric.Image.fromURL('../lib/pug.jpg', function(img) {

    canvas.add(img.set({ left: 250, top: 250, angle: 30 }).scale(0.25));

    img.on('moving', function() { positionBtn(img) });
    positionBtn(img);
  });
})();
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: In angular its gives Property 'getAbsoluteCoords' does not exist on type 'Canvas'.