# Fabric js text, vertical align to center

Tags: fabricjs

I am using fabric.js library. I want to vertically align text to ceneter of textbox area. Please see image.

[image: Text]

In image default cursor is align to top but i want it to center. Is there any property for text as `valign` like `textalign`?

Tried `originY` but no luck.

Comment: Are you using fabricjs 2.x?

Comment: No, I am using fabricjs1.x

Comment: I guess there is 3 lines, thats why its showing on top line center

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem. I am also stuck on the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

fabric.js 3.5.1 works with `originY: 'center'`
see [FabricJS: Vertical Align text center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656603/fabricjs-vertical-align-text-center/59269666#59269666)

.... but the bounding-box has no "minimum height" setting
and paddingX / paddingY are not supported by fabric

to solve this in fabric,
you must override the render function, as shown in
[Draw border on Fabric Textbox when it's not selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233082/draw-border-on-fabric-textbox-when-its-not-selected)

but it should be easier to use html elements,
and put them over your canvas, as shown in
[How to put an html element over a fabric.js element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507133/how-to-put-an-html-element-over-a-fabric-js-element)